# Completely turn off OS X Websites

Tags: osx-server

I'd like to run OS X Server, but not the website portion of it, as I'm using something else for that.

I'm trying to run SiriProxy, which must run on port 443, but that is currently in use even though web services are turned off. When I visit 127.0.0.1:443, I get the "web service is currently turned off" message.

How do I completely turn off web services and allow another process to listen on 443?

Comment: What services are green when you use the server app to look at all running services?

Comment: I'm running Time Machine, DNS, VPN, Caching and File Sharing

Comment: I'll be able to test later today, but that list is pretty clean. My guess would be caching uses SSL web for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Check your httpd.conf file in /private/etc/apache2/ and see if you have the line:

```
listen 443
```

If it's there, comment out by prepending the line with '#'

```
# listen 443
```

The restart your server service.